# Gitlab remove old commits

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit

I have cloned a repo from gitlab. Without removing the .git folder i have worked and edited the cloned project and done certain commits.Now my gitlab has old commits as well as my commits .Is there any way to remove old commits and maintain my commits only.?Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to remove old commits?  You could have tried a shallow clone, where you brought in the history only to a point.

Comment: Please be more clear about `worked and edited`. Have you rewritten history?

Comment: The cloned repo is done by some one else so the commits has his commits too, but after cloning that am suppose to do is to create new repo and push this cloned project to new repo and work on that.but before pushing to new repo i haven't deleted the .git folder so the new repo commit has my commits as well as old repo's commits i need my commit only.Hope this is clear thanks..

Comment: if i delete the .git folder and start from the beginning like git init ... the new commits so far i done in my new repo will be deleted no?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is create a new empty repo, and import in it only your new commits from your current (mixted) repo.

```
cd /another/local/path/aNewFolder
git init .
git remote add mixtedRepo /path/to/mixted/repo
git fetch mixtedRepo
```

So far, your new repo is empty, and there is a `mixtedRepo/master` remote branch in it (with old and new commits).

Let's make sure you have a local master branch first:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "master branch"
```

Then, let's rebase on your lone empty commit the commits you did in your old repo:

```
git rebase --onto master <your First New Commit SHA1> mixtedRepo/master
```

Finally, let's push that to a new remote GitLab repo:

```
git remote add origin /url/new/empty/GitLab/repo
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @VonC let me check.